# Vuetify V-Data-Table search not working when :items refer to computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an app with a v-data-table where the :items are reffering to a computed property array. I dont know why, but the search function doesnt work and it makes me furious for hours.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I even added the item-key property and the items id to it which I usually never did in the past but it still doesnt work. Can anyone give me a hint?

```js
 <v-data-table
          :search="search"
          :loading="loading"
          class="transparent"
          dense
          fixed-header
          height="800"
          :items="filteredItems"
          :headers="headers"
          item-key="id"
         
        >
```

```js
 filteredItems() {
      let items = this.items;

      items = items.filter(
        item =>
          Number(item.attributes.token0_usd_value) >=
          Number(this.showMinUSDValue)
      );

      items = items.filter(
        item => item.attributes.new_position == this.newPositions
      );

      if (this.wallet_group !== "ALL") {
        items = items.filter(
          item => item.attributes.group == this.wallet_group
        );
      }

      if (this.tradeSide !== "ALL") {
        items = items.filter(
          item => item.attributes.side.toUpperCase() == this.tradeSide
        );
      }

      if (this.time_filter !== "ALL") {
        const timestamp = this.getTimestampForInterval(this.time_filter);

        items = items.filter(item => {
          return (
            new Date(item.attributes.block_timestamp).getTime() > timestamp
          );
        });
      }

      if (this.excludedSymbols.length > 0) {
        items = items.filter(item => {
          return (
            !this.excludedSymbols.includes(
              item.attributes.token0.attributes.symbol
            ) &&
            !this.excludedSymbols.includes(
              item.attributes.token1.attributes.symbol
            )
          );
        });
      }

      return items;
    }
  },
```

```js
<template>
  <keep-alive>
    <v-card class="transparent">
      <v-card-title class="text-uppercase primary--text">
        Dex Trades
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-subtitle>
        follow realtime dex trades for address pool
        <v-row class="mt-6">
          <v-col cols="12" md="2" lg="1">
            <v-text-field
              outlined
              dense
              label="$USD min"
              v-model="showMinUSDValue"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" md="1">
            <v-select
              dense
              outlined
              :items="time_filters"
              v-model="time_filter"
              label="time"
            ></v-select
          ></v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" md="1">
            <v-select
              dense
              outlined
              :items="wallet_groups"
              v-model="wallet_group"
              label="group"
            ></v-select
          ></v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" md="1">
            <v-select
              dense
              outlined
              :items="tradeSideItems"
              v-model="tradeSide"
              label="side"
            ></v-select
          ></v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" md="1">
            <v-checkbox
              dense
              label="only new"
              v-model="newPositions"
            ></v-checkbox>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" md="1">
            <v-checkbox
              dense
              label="notifications"
              v-model="playAudio"
            ></v-checkbox>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row class="mt-0 pa-0">
          <v-col cols="12" md="4">
            <v-autocomplete
              small-chips
              dense
              chips
              multiple
              :items="symbols"
              v-model="excludedSymbols"
              label="exclude symbols"
            ></v-autocomplete>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" md="2">
            <v-text-field
              dense
              name="search"
              label="search symbol"
              v-model="search"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-card-subtitle>

      <v-card-text>
        {{filteredItems.length}}
        <v-data-table
          disable-pagination
          :loading="loading"
          class="transparent"
          dense
          fixed-header
          height="800"
          :items="filteredItems"
          :headers="headers"
          item-key="id"
        >
          <template v-slot:item.logo="{ item }">
            <v-img
              v-if="item.attributes.side == 'sell'"
              contain
              width="25"
              height="25"
              style="border-radius:50%"
              :src="item.attributes.token0_ticker.attributes.image"
              :lazy-src="item.attributes.token0_ticker.attributes.image"
            ></v-img>
            <v-img
              v-else
              contain
              width="25"
              height="25"
              style="border-radius:50%"
              :src="item.attributes.token1_ticker.attributes.image"
              :lazy-src="item.attributes.token1_ticker.attributes.image"
            ></v-img>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:item.attributes.side="{ item }">
            <div
              v-if="item.attributes.side === 'sell'"
              class="error--text text-uppercase"
            >
              {{ item.attributes.side }}
            </div>
            <div v-else class="success--text text-uppercase">
              {{ item.attributes.side }}
            </div>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:item.ticker="{ item }">
            <div>
              <div v-if="item.attributes.side == 'sell'">
                {{ item.attributes.token0.attributes.symbol }}
              </div>
              <div v-else>{{ item.attributes.token1.attributes.symbol }}</div>
            </div>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:item.attributes.token0_usd_value="{ item }">
            {{ getFormattedPrice(item.attributes.token0_usd_value) }}
          </template>
          <template v-slot:item.flow="{ item }">
            <div v-html="getFlow(item)"></div>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:item.newPosition="{ item }">
            <v-icon v-if="item.attributes.new_position == true" color="success"
              >mdi-check-bold</v-icon
            >
            <v-icon v-else color="error">mdi-close-thick</v-icon>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:item.current="{ item }">
            {{ getCurrentBalance(item) }}
          </template>
          <template v-slot:item.holdingsDifference="{ item }">
            {{ getTokenHoldingsChange(item) }}
          </template>
          <template v-slot:item.address="{ item }">
            <a
              target="blank"
              :href="getEtherscanURL('address', item.attributes.address)"
            >
              <div>
                {{
                  item.attributes.address.substr(
                    item.attributes.address.length - 5
                  )
                }}
              </div></a
            >
          </template>
          <template v-slot:item.prev="{ item }">
            {{ getPreviousBalance(item) }}
          </template>
          <template v-slot:item.attributes.block_timestamp="{ item }">
            {{ convertTimezone(item) }}
          </template>
          <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
            <v-btn
              class="mr-2"
              small
              rounded
              :href="getEtherscanURL('tx', item.attributes.transaction_hash)"
              target="_blank"
              color="warning"
              >tx</v-btn
            >
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </keep-alive>
</template>

<script>
import Moralis from "moralis";
import syncAPI from "../../api/sync/sync.api";

const sound = require("@/assets/notification.mp3");
export default {
  name: "Realtime-Table",
  data: () => ({
    search: "",
    items: [],
    newPositions: false,
    loading: false,
    showMinUSDValue: 25000,
    notification: null,
    playAudio: true,
    wallet_group: "ALL",
    tradeSide: "ALL",
    tradeSideItems: ["ALL", "BUY", "SELL"],
    wallet_groups: [],
    excludedSymbols: [],
    time_filter: "ALL",
    time_filters: ["1m", "5m", "15m", "30m", "1h", "4h", "1d", "1w", "ALL"],
    headers: [
      {
        text: "ticker",
        align: "center",
        value: "ticker",
        class: "background primary--text text-uppercase font-weight-black"
      },
      {
        text: "buy/sell",
        align: "start",
        value: "attributes.side",
        class: "background primary--text text-uppercase font-weight-black"
      },
      {
        text: "flow",
        align: "center",
        value: "flow",
        class: "background primary--text text-uppercase font-weight-black"
      },
      {
        text: "dex",
        align: "start",
        value: "attributes.dex.attributes.identifier",
        class: "background primary--text text-uppercase font-weight-black"
      },
      {
        text: "$amount",
        align: "start",
        value: "attributes.token0_usd_value",
        class: "background primary--text text-uppercase font-weight-black"
      },
      {
        text: "$prev",
        align: "start",
        value: "prev",
        class: "background primary--text text-uppercase font-weight-black"
      },
      {
        text: "$current",
        align: "start",
        value: "current",
        class: "background primary--text text-uppercase font-weight-black"
      },

      {
        text: "address",
        align: "start",
        value: "address",
        class: "background primary--text text-uppercase font-weight-black"
      },
      {
        text: "new position",
        align: "center",
        value: "newPosition",
        class: "background primary--text text-uppercase font-weight-black"
      },
      {
        text: "timestamp",
        align: "start",
        value: "attributes.block_timestamp",
        class: "background primary--text text-uppercase font-weight-black"
      },

      {
        text: "actions",
        align: "center",
        value: "actions",
        class: "background primary--text text-uppercase font-weight-black"
      }
    ]
  }),

  computed: {
    symbols() {
      const unique = [
        ...new Set(
          this.items.map(item => item.attributes.token0.attributes.symbol)
        )
      ];
      return unique;
    },
    filteredItems() {
      let items = this.items;

      items = items.filter(item => {
        return (
          item.attributes.token1.attributes.symbol.includes(
            this.search.toUpperCase()
          ) ||
          item.attributes.token0.attributes.symbol.includes(
            this.search.toUpperCase()
          )
        );
      });

      items = items.filter(
        item =>
          Number(item.attributes.token0_usd_value) >=
          Number(this.showMinUSDValue)
      );

      items = items.filter(
        item => item.attributes.new_position == this.newPositions
      );

      if (this.wallet_group !== "ALL") {
        items = items.filter(
          item => item.attributes.group == this.wallet_group
        );
      }

      if (this.tradeSide !== "ALL") {
        items = items.filter(
          item => item.attributes.side.toUpperCase() == this.tradeSide
        );
      }

      if (this.time_filter !== "ALL") {
        const timestamp = this.getTimestampForInterval(this.time_filter);

        items = items.filter(item => {
          return (
            new Date(item.attributes.block_timestamp).getTime() > timestamp
          );
        });
      }

      if (this.excludedSymbols.length > 0) {
        items = items.filter(item => {
          return (
            !this.excludedSymbols.includes(
              item.attributes.token0.attributes.symbol
            ) &&
            !this.excludedSymbols.includes(
              item.attributes.token1.attributes.symbol
            )
          );
        });
      }

      return items;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getTimestampForInterval() {
      switch (this.time_filter) {
        case "5m":
          return Date.now() - 5 * 1000 * 60;
        case "10m":
          return Date.now() - 10 * 1000 * 60;
        case "15m":
          return Date.now() - 15 * 1000 * 60;
        case "30m":
          return Date.now() - 30 * 1000 * 60;
        case "1h":
          return Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60;
        case "4h":
          return Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 4;
        case "8h":
          return Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 8;
        case "12h":
          return Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12;
        case "1d":
          return Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        case "1w":
          return Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
        case "1m":
          return Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
        default:
          return Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 5;
      }
    },

    getTokenHoldingsChange(item) {
      if (item.side == "buy") {
        return Number(
          item.attributes.token1_current_balance.amount_decimal -
            item.attributes.token1_previous_balance.amount_decimal
        ).toFixed(5);
      }
      return Number(
        item.attributes.token0_current_balance.amount_decimal -
          item.attributes.token0_previous_balance.amount_decimal
      ).toFixed(2);
    },
    getCurrentBalance(item) {
      if (item.attributes.side == "buy") {
        return this.getFormattedPrice(
          item.attributes.token1_current_balance.amount_decimal *
            item.attributes.token1_current_balance.price.usdPrice
        );
      }
      return this.getFormattedPrice(
        item.attributes.token0_current_balance.amount_decimal *
          item.attributes.token0_current_balance.price.usdPrice
      );
    },
    getPreviousBalance(item) {
      if (item.attributes.side == "buy") {
        return this.getFormattedPrice(
          item.attributes.token1_previous_balance.amount_decimal *
            item.attributes.token1_previous_balance.price.usdPrice
        );
      }
      return this.getFormattedPrice(
        item.attributes.token0_previous_balance.amount_decimal *
          item.attributes.token0_previous_balance.price.usdPrice
      );
    },
    getFlow(item) {
      const side = item.attributes.side;
      if (side.toUpperCase() == "SELL") {
        return `<div class="d-flex justify-center"><div class="error--text">${item.attributes.token0.attributes.symbol}</div> / <div class="success--text">${item.attributes.token1.attributes.symbol}</div></div>`;
      }

      return `<div class="d-flex justify-center"><div class="success--text">${item.attributes.token1.attributes.symbol}</div> / <div class="error--text">${item.attributes.token0.attributes.symbol}</div></div>`;
    },
    getFormattedPrice(number) {
      return number.toLocaleString("en-US", {
        style: "currency",
        currency: "USD"
      });
    },
    getEtherscanURL(type, value) {
      if (type === "tx") return `https://etherscan.io/tx/${value}`;
      return `https://etherscan.io/address/${value}`;
    },

    convertTimezone(item) {
      if (item.attributes.block_timestamp)
        return item.attributes.block_timestamp.toLocaleString("en-US", {
          timeZone: "EST"
        });

      return "";
    },

    async subscribeToTransactions() {
      try {
        let query = new Moralis.Query("DexTrade");
        query.include("dex");
        query.include("token0");
        query.include("token1");
        query.include("token0_ticker");
        query.include("token1_ticker");
        let subscription = await query.subscribe();
        subscription.on("open", () => {
          console.log("DexTrades subscription opened");
        });
        subscription.on("create", object => {
          console.log("obj before check", object.attributes);

          if (
            object.attributes.token0_current_balance.price &&
            object.attributes.token0_previous_balance.price &&
            object.attributes.token1_current_balance.price &&
            object.attributes.token1_previous_balance.price
          ) {
            this.items.unshift(object);

            if (this.playAudio) {
              this.notification.play();
            }
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    },
    async loadPreviousTransactions() {
      const query = new Moralis.Query("DexTrade");
      this.loading = true;
      query.include("dex");
      query.include("token0");
      query.include("token1");
      query.include("token0_ticker");
      query.include("token1_ticker");
      query.limit(500);
      query.descending("createdAt");
      this.items = await query.find();
      this.loading = false;
    }
  },
  async created() {
    this.notification = new Audio(sound);
    this.wallet_groups = await syncAPI.walletGroups();
    await this.loadPreviousTransactions();
    await this.subscribeToTransactions();
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.element .v-data-table__wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 24px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #143861;
}
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td {
  font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: If you want help, "doesnt work" is not enough accurate description of the problem

Comment: Really? Doesnt work to me means it does not work and is simple enough. It is not working. Whenever I search for something, it is not filtering the data

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by not working? What specifically isn't working, do you have an error message, what is rendered?

Comment: Also, you snippets do not actually run, you should either include the rest of the component, or convert into a code block (instead of an interactive snippets)

Comment: There is no error output, when the table for example has a column "flow" and a value inside of "WETH/BTC" and I type WETH/BTC in the search text field, the table result is completely empty afterwards. I dont know if its because most fields are generated within templates I dont know.

Comment: See? I'm not only one who want more details. Yes, "does not work" in not enough. From the component perspective computed property is as good data source as any other. Did you check Dev Tools for any errors?

Comment: Yes, no errors shown. I will paste the whole component in here, maybe that helps to find out why it is not working.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. For those think `does not work` is not enough, you simple don't know this problem.

Comment: @BitQueen can you make it work?